# Angular 2 sorting the components' views that were dynamically created?

Tags: angular

I dynamically create some components like:

```
let comFac = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(com)
let newCom: ComponentRef<any> = viewContain.createComponent(comFac)
newCom.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

Then I push the `newCom` into a temp array like:

```
this.comArr.push(newCom)
```

And the `viewContain` can show these components'view correctly.Now I want to dynamically sort these components' view by some operations like drag them.How to make the `viewContain` can show the view after components were dragged but not create them(components) again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
viewContain.move(newCom.hostView, someNewIndex);
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html